# Rgb decode from 7-digit number

Tags: javascript, rgb

I'm trying to get rgb from my wifi bulb, but I'm getting this: "2442110"

How do I decode it? I've tried to search about it but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you convert this integer to hex you'll see the following

```
>>> hex(2442110)
'0x25437e'
```

I would guess that this can be broken into RGB as

```
(0x25, 0x43, 0x7e)  # hex
(37, 67, 126)  # decimal
```

So starting with your original integer, first convert to a hex string, then use string slicing to extract each component, and finally convert back to `int` (base-10 i.e. decimal)

```
>>> s = hex(2442110)
>>> [int(s[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(2, 7, 2)]
[37, 67, 126]
```